# How to use a template when adding a new row to kendo ui grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I add a row to a kendo grid I need to be able to use a template in one cell and not sure how to do that..
To add a new row I use

```
grid.dataSource.insert(0, { AreaID: null, AreaName: "New Area", Catalog: 2 });
```

but what I am trying to do is where it says Catalog, I need to add a dropdown to that.. I tried something like this as a test

```
grid.dataSource.insert(0, { AreaID: null, AreaName: "New Area", Catalog: '<div>acd</div>' });
```

but all that did was have my catalog column show as undefined.

Any idea's how I can add a dropdown to the Catalog column when adding a new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following line of code for adding column in grid

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: dataSource,

          pageable: true,
          height: 430,
          toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
          columns: [

            { template: "<input data-bind='value:ProductName' />", title: "Product Name", width: 110 },
            { template: "<input data-bind='value:UnitsInStock' />", title: "Units In Stock", width: 110 },
            { field: "Discontinued", width: 110 },
            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 90 }],
          editable: true,
          dataBound: onDataBound
        });
```

For more details:-[We can refer the Kendo Document](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/grid-editors-in-column-templates)